# How to show chat thread in Cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am 2-month new to Cocoa and Objective-C and right now struggling with a problem in which I need to create a chat application.

**Task**
I need to show chat threads like (below):
[image]

**Problem**

I donot know which control can show chat like this so,could you please suggest which NSView Control should I use? Many thanks for your attention.

S.P: I have XCode 6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no predefined NSView subclass that can do this, as it is a quite special problem you address.
Therefore, you have to make your own one.

I would start with an NSTableView and some custom cells. 
Each cell gets some custom drawing to get the speech bubble design and a self-growing NSTextField.

Then you have to make sure that each cell grows individually, depending on how much text it holds.

Comment: Sir, Is there any tutorial on how can we customize the NSTableView's cells at that level. Any help would be more than enough. Many thanks for guiding

Comment: Well, I did not find any, but take a look at those projects: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18572250/4113940  - Even thought they are for iOS, you get the idea.

Comment: For the beginning: Use a tutorial to find out how to subclass NSTableViewCell. With that you can work with the NSTextField. Make this work first.

Comment: You can worry about the design later. There are multiple things you can do. Subclass NSTableViewCell and insert your custom drawing code OR use images.